# Autofac with xml / json configuration

Tags: c#, configuration, autofac

I'm a little lost on the examples at http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#configuring-with-microsoft-configuration

After poking around for ages not realising I also had to add the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json package (and they were only in pre-release), I now get an error on:
var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());

I get a compile error about not being able to  instantiate an abstract class.

There's no mention in the docs about having to ref any other package.  Any ideas?

Comment: It would be good to post the actual exception so we know what the abstract type is that it's failing on.

Comment: If you don't want to use JSON - you want XML - then you don't need a reference to that JSON package. If you're only using environment variables or in-memory config, you don't need either. That's why the docs don't tell you exactly which packages to reference. The new MS config stuff is very flexible and Autofac allows full use of that flexibility.

Also note - if you're not into pre-release stuff, you can use the legacy XML config (see the latter part of that page).

Comment: The was no exception, just symbols not resolving when writing the code.

Comment: I told you, the symbol could not be resolved because I didnt' have the right reference.  The whole poitn of this question was to derive the referecne I required.

Comment: If you read the original question it clearly states "I get a compile error about not being able to instantiate an abstract class" in relation to 'var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());'
It's pretty clear I wanted to know why the symbol "ConfigurationModule" couldn't be found. Anyway, this conversation needs to end now otherwise some insults ensue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so what I had to do was instal the pre release version which solved my issues

I was using the current stable.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen noted, the documentation covers the prerelease API by default. You can access documentation for the currently supported XML configuration process by toggling the green `v:Latest` in the bottom left corner of the docs, which will give you the option of switching to the current stable release:

[image: Latest] >>
[image: 3.5.2]